# UIImage+RoundedCorner with SDWebImage

Tags: iphone, image, load, resize, tableview

I am using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to load images into my table view. I would like the images in my table view to be resized and have round corners. I found [UIImage+Resize and UIImage+RoundedCorner](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) to do this. Both libraries works great seperately but I have not been abl to combine them. I could resize and round the corners of the image SDWebImage returns but I have found this to be fairly resource heavy and therefore I would like to have the images resized before saving them to the cache.
When an image is loaded from the net for the first time it is probably shown before being saved to the cache therefore I would also like to resize the image when it is loaded for the first time.

I have not been able to do this as I cannot figure out which method of SDWebImage to manipulate the image in. All I need is to call the following on the right UIImage in SDWebImage.

```
UIImage *image = [image thumbnailImage:50 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:5 interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
```

Can anyone tell me where in SDWebImage I should place this piece of code to have the image manipulated before being saved to the cache and have a manipulated image sent to the image view when it is loaded from the internet and not the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.

You should manipulate the image in the following methods in SDImageCache.m:

```
 1. - (void)storeImage:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key;
 2. - (void)storeImage:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key toDisk:(BOOL)toDisk;
 3. - (void)storeImage:(UIImage *)image imageData:(NSData *)data forKey:(NSString *)key toDisk:(BOOL)toDisk;
```

In the third method you must remember to convert your UIImage to NSData using the code below. This should be done if `toDisk` is true.

```
NSData *croppedRoundedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedRoundedImage, 1.0);
if (croppedRoundedImageData) data = croppedRoundedImageData;
```

Using `if (croppedRoundedImageData) data = croppedRoundedImageData;` your app will not crash if your data is `NULL` when you try to save it.

In SDWebImageDownloader.m you must add your code for manipulating in `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection` This is used for the first load of the image (when not in cache)

Answer (score 8):

For the resize image part, I don't have a good answer.

For the round corners feature, you are completely going to the wrong way, this is what I try to do before... try to resize and round every image and save it to the disk...... too complex, too many things to do...

the correct and simple way is to set the UIImageView cornerRadius of your table cell:

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Fast and easy way, but affects performance. Rendering images with cut corners is better in terms of tableview performance

Answer (score 1):

The SDWebImageManagerDelegate protocol is what you're looking for.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImageManager.h#LC96

I implemented the method we need in my AppDelegate class.

```
#pragma mark - SDWebImageManagerDelegate

-(UIImage*) imageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager transformDownloadedImage:(UIImage *)image withURL:(NSURL *)imageURL{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    CGRect box = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    // Add a clip before drawing anything, in the shape of an rounded rect
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:box
                                cornerRadius:15.f] addClip];
    // Draw your image
    [image drawInRect:box];

    // Get the image, here setting the UIImageView image
    UIImage* ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Lets forget about that we were drawing
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return ret;

}
```

You can tell the sharedManager to use your delegate like this.

```
SDWebImageManager* imageManager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
imageManager.delegate = self;
```

I did this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Keep in mind that this approach clips along the bounds of the image at it's native size. If the bounds of your image are being rendered outside the bounds of your view (aspect-fill, etc), you will not see the rounded corners.

This approach is more performant than clipping the image every time it's rendered, but be aware of the above disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great find, but I find that by adding your image manipulation code in SDWebImageDownloader.m it makes thumbnails for all images using SDWebImage. What I did was create an SDWebImageManager instance and used the method:

```
- (void) webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image;
```

to create the images, the only problem is because the images come in different times I'm trying to find a way to link them properly with an action.

Great answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Im using SDWebImage framework which doesn't give me the ability to modify the files but i have a global function like this:

```
     + (UIImage*)circleImageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
      {
          UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
          CALayer *layer = [imageView layer];
          [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
          [layer setCornerRadius:imageView.frame.size.width / 2];

          UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
          [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
          UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
          return newImage;
      }
```

and global funtion to scale image like this:

```
      + (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
      {   
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
          [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
          UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
          return newImage;
      }
```